# Error in code in python

Tags: python

```
data=open('D:\\e.txt','r',encoding='utf-8')
x= data.readlines()

tw= x.split(',"text":" ')[1].split('","source')[0]
```

i have problem

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: Change `x.readlines()` to `x.read()`

Answer (score 0):

`readlines()` returns a list of all the lines in a file. Whereas split() is a string method. As @inspectorG4dget suggested if you want to use `split()`, use `read()` which returns the contents of a file as string.

```
data=open('D:\\file_path','r')
x= data.read()
tw= x.split("separator")
```